Create local Windows 10 user and programmatically answer the privacy/advertising questions
I'm looking to create a local Windows 10 user via PowerShell, and then finalize the 'account setup' programmatically.
If I currently create a new user User1 via New-LocalUser, and I manually sign in as User1 then I first get a 'Welcome, we're getting everything ready for you' screen and then I need to answer questions about using online speech recognition, location data, inking & typing, diagnostic data and advertising ID.
I would like to programmatically provide the answers to those questions and finalize the account setup, so that when User1 actually signs in, the questions no longer appear.
I've already found how to partially initialize the user profile by running 'Start-Process' with -LoadUserProfile: this creates e.g. the user folder in C:\Users, but it doesn't remove the questions.

I think you're looking to disable the first sign-in animation and privacy settings experience. As per links, you could do this via the registry, but really this is something that should be set at a group policy level.
